# How to display posts from sub folders at the homepage of my wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to display posts from two different sub directories of my WordPress blog at the homepage, so I created `gidiok.com/ng` as well as `gidiok.com/gh` and I want to display posts from those two directories at homepage which is `gidiok.com`

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may have better luck posting this on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic before posting a question.

Comment: A wordpress website doesn't have 'sub directories' as such.  If these are separate wp installs, then you could use their rss feeds, and displays those using the rss widget.

Comment: OK, that is separate WP installations. Can you suggest a plugin that can handle that with RSS feeds?

Comment: Just use the built in WP-JSON API, it's pretty well documented.